# Collation sort with object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uilocalizedcollation

I have a list view and want to sort the array so that each of the names is under the correct `UILocalizedIndexCollation` section.
Here is a snippet of the section that is being passed in. I want to sort via the `name` however I also want to keep the object intact so I can user other data.

```
2012-03-23 12:10:14.083 MyApp[61241:14803] Section: (
        {
        "c_id" = 261;
        "customer_id" = 178664;
        "first_name" = My;
        "last_name" = Test;
        name = "Test, My";
    },
        {
        "c_id" = 261;
        "customer_id" = 185182;
        "first_name" = valid;
        "last_name" = Test;
        name = "Test, valid";
    },
        {
        "c_id" = 261;
        "customer_id" = 178729;
        "first_name" = Test;
        "last_name" = Three;
        name = "Three, Test";
    },
        {
        "c_id" = 261;
        "customer_id" = 178727;
        "first_name" = Test;
        "last_name" = Two;
        name = "Two, Test";
    },
        {
        "c_id" = 261;
        "customer_id" = 178728;
        "first_name" = Test;
        "last_name" = Two;
        name = "Two, Test";
    }
)
```

Partition

```
-(NSArray *)partitionObjects:(NSArray *)array collationStringSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    UILocalizedIndexedCollation *collation = [UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation];
    NSInteger sectionCount = [[collation sectionTitles] count];
    NSMutableArray *unsortedSections = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:sectionCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < sectionCount; i++) {
        [unsortedSections addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];
    }

    for (id object in array) {
        NSInteger index = [collation sectionForObject:[object objectForKey:@"name"] collationStringSelector:selector];
        [[unsortedSections objectAtIndex:index] addObject:object];
    }

    NSMutableArray *sections = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:sectionCount];

    for (NSMutableArray *section in unsortedSections) {
        [sections addObject:[collation sortedArrayFromArray:section collationStringSelector:selector]];
    }

    return sections;
}
```

Calling the partition

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        NSMutableArray *tempCustomers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSString *name;
        for (NSDictionary *dict in [json objectForKey:@"data"]) {
            name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",[dict objectForKey:@"last_name"],[dict objectForKey:@"first_name"]];
            NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:dict];
            [tempDict setValue:name forKey:@"name"];
            [tempCustomers addObject:tempDict];

        }

        self.customers = tempCustomers;
        self.customerData = [self partitionObjects:[self customers] collationStringSelector:@selector(self)];
```

I am needing to keep the object intact but sort by name and have each of the objects be placed into their appropriate sections with `UILocalizedIndexCollation`

**ANSWER CODE USED:**

```
-(NSArray *)partitionObjects:(NSArray *)array collationStringSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    UILocalizedIndexedCollation *collation = [UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation];
    NSInteger sectionCount = [[collation sectionTitles] count];
    NSMutableArray *unsortedSections = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:sectionCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < sectionCount; i++) {
        [unsortedSections addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];
    }

    for (id object in array) {
        NSInteger index = [collation sectionForObject:[object objectForKey:@"name"] collationStringSelector:selector];
        [[unsortedSections objectAtIndex:index] addObject:object];
    }

    NSMutableArray *sections = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:sectionCount];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];


    for (NSMutableArray *section in unsortedSections) {
        NSArray *sortedArray = [section sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
        collationStringSelector:selector]];
        [sections addObject:sortedArray];
    }

    return sections;
}
```

Comment: This might be helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it

Comment: Can you please place the code here?

Comment: @Flink what do you mean? The code is posted above.

Comment: @Flink there is code in the linked answer. Or are you wanting the code that I ended up using?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I checked the link, but found that I can't understand how to implement it with UILocalizedIndexCollation, so if you still have the code you did, please publish it

Comment: @Flink I think the edit is what you are looking for. Been so long ago though, I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it with a compare method.

A good example of that is provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/805589/580291

Comment: This worked perfect. I thought I would have to use it with a collation sort but NOPE! Thanks!